# Is there any specific reason to use "else if" clause?

Tags: programming-languages, algorithms

We all use if ..else if.. else.

But still I'm confused as to why we use **else if**. Where **if** does the same thing as **else if**.

So why are we using **else if**?

Any specific reasons behind this?

Is there any algorithm where it's mandatory to use **else if**?

Comment: You could actually ask why use `else` at all (not just the `else if` combo). After all, one can always write `if (a) ... if (!a)` instead. Well, it's just more expressive.

Comment: PLUS `if (a) doSomething else doSomethingElse` ensures that if `doSomething` was executed, `doSomethingElse` won't. `if (a) doSomething; if (!a) doSomethingElse` makes it possible (if `a` was true before `doSomething`, but `doSomething` changed its value to false).

Comment: Why, it's nothing special? You could also ask "Is there a specific reason we use *else while*, *else return*, *else assignment*, ..."

Comment: It is used to denote multiple branching targets when all of the conditions are mutually exclusive (disjoint). In some languages, `switch case` have been extended to handle mutually exclusive branching thus making `else if` optional. In C and C++, this is not the case because of historical reasons.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The main reason to use `else if` is to avoid excessive indentation.

For example:

```
    if(a) {
    } else {
        if(b) {
        } else {
            if(c) {
            } else {
            }
        }
    }
```

Can become:

```
    if(a) {
    } else if(b) {
    } else if(c) {
    }
```

Of course both of the pieces of code above are equivalent (which means it's impossible for the latter to be mandatory other than in style guides).

Comment: Another option would be: if(a) { } if(!a && b) {} if(!a && !b && c) {} Just imagine this madness for more and bigger conditions.

Comment: yeah. nice explanation. +votes to both of you .. thanks

Comment: @RanjitPati: Side note: There is no such thing as an "else if". It does not exist in [the language grammar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html). "else" goes down the next statement if the if statement is false, and an if statement is a statement. Essentially, the answer to this question is "You are using an if statement already".

Comment: @Phoshi hit the nail right on the head.

Comment: **if..else if..** is a very bad code smell.  It is often a source of error and even where there is no error it is usually a sign of poor code structure.

Comment: @Phoshi Which is interesting to note, because it means constructs like `if (bool) { ... } else try { ... } catch { ... }` are entirely valid. It's probably not advisable, because most people aren't used to seeing it written that way, but the same principle applies.

Comment: @Flo it's not synonymous. Eg. if `a` is true, but it changes to false WITHIN the first `if (a)` block, the code will behave differently and `if (!a && b)` may be executed as well. So there is a semantic difference. These blocks are not mutually exclusive anymore.

Comment: @Phoshi Just because it doesn't exist in Java does not mean it doesn't exist at all. For example, perl has it.

Comment: @itsbruce: That’s hilarious—please tell me you’re not serious!

Comment: @Phoshi In addition to Perl's `elseif`, we also have `elsif` in bash and `elif` in Python.  Probably others as well, those are just the ones I know.

Comment: @Izkata: Right you are, of course. The question had a `Java` tag at the time, though. There are various languages with structures similar to if/else if actually defined in the grammar, if we're being language agnostic.

Comment: Language that have special `elseif` statements are the ones where braces/indentation/etc are always required after an `else` statement. Languages that do not have this feature can simply use `else if`

Answer (score 8):

the question asks, "why do you need else given that you can accomplish the same functionality using only if" (paraphrased). First of all, the two are only really equivalent in fairly simple programs; there are many situations where else if functionality cannot be easily replicated using only if statements.

that said, in such simple situations it is still usually better to use else if.

```
if (a==b){}
if (!(a==b) && a==c ){}
```

there are two problems with this that are solved by using else if. First, you perform the comparison between a and b twice, which is unnecessary work. Second, unless you memorize the rules or rely heavily on parenthesis, it's not obvious how the second boolean expression resolves.

```
if (a==b) {}
else if (a==c) {}
```

Is cleaner, clearer, and more efficient. It's basically the programming holy grail.

Comment: You do understand there is a difference between those two statements right? In your first example both statements will always be checked. In the second the second will only be checked if the first one is false. This difference is the reason for the downvote.  To make the first one equal place the if statement within an else statement.

Comment: There's a semantic difference as well. If `a` or `b`, or `c` changes within the first block (`if (a==b)`), both blocks may get executed. `if - else if` is insensitive to that.  As for "unnecessary work" - this sort of performance hit is typically irrelevant, unless eg. `a` and `b` are methods that take long to evaluate. It's also a rather poor sign if a programmer hasn't memorized the rules required to understand how `(!(a==b) && a==c )` evaluates.

Comment: For more complicated expressions, as might arise from attempting to chain this along for any significant length, the boolean expression can become substantially unclear...particularly if some of the previous ifs used a complicated predicate itself -- (!(a&b==c) && (c >d || d==5) && ((a*d > g) && !(a > 12))...) might be easily parsed into sub expressions, but certainly isn't _clear_

Answer (score 4):

It's for efficiency.  If you have a chain of `if...else if...else if` clauses, then evaluation stops after one evaluates to true.  If you simply have a list of `if` clauses, then even after one evaluates to true, you'll still check the rest of them, even though they'll be false. If the conditions involve invoking functions or other "expensive" operations then you'll waste resources (especially if your conditions involve web service calls or database lookups).  This is also why you should try to structure complicated conditional expressions like this so that the "cheapest" conditions are checked first.

Comment: Efficiency is the least important consideration, if it is one at all. Readability and maintainability trump it. The most important is correctness and ability to easily reason in the face of mutability.

Answer (score 3):

If we think programmatically the main purpose is if we have to choose one thing among many things at that time we should use `else if`.

Also there can be many ways of doing same things like `switch..case` in that case we can consider it as another construct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with if and else if... You will definitely understand the difference.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int time = 5;
    if (time < 10) {
        printf("It is less than Ten");
    } if (time < 20) {
        printf("It is less than Twenty");
    } else {
        printf("High");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of days in a year is 365, except every four years it is 366, except every 100 years it is 365, except every 400 years it is 366. (There was lots of code getting it wrong in the year 2,000, and there will be lots of code around that will get it wrong in 2,100).

Write a function calculating the number of days in a year correctly, once using “else if”, once withou using “else if”. Tell us what is more readable and shorter code.

Comment: `return 365 + !(year % 4) - !(year % 100) + !(year % 400);` ;-)

Comment: That is evil. And I mean it. Not passing any code review. And doesn’t compile in Java or Swift.

Comment: It's a very straight-forward translation for languages where it works. Not debating that there are many where it doesn't. Of course, there is a school of thought which says that if it doesn't work like that in language X, coding it like that in language Y is bad. Or that implicit conversions are inherently evil. Whether it should pass code review? Cannot be simplified (I think), hard to make more concise (the argument could be simply `n` , depending on the function-name), should be efficient enough (branching often dominates extra calculation, and who knows what the compiler decides), ...